# Java trim character and whitespaces

Tags: java, string, annotations, character, whitespace

Reading the annotation on top of Java TestNG test and I have annotation as:

```
@TestInfo(id={ " C26603", " C10047" })
```

where `TestInfo` is just the interface that has `id() as String array`:

```
public String[] id() default {};
```

and `C26603` and `C10047` are just test ids that I assign.

Here is how test structure looks like (for example):

***CASE 1***:

```
@TestInfo(id={ " C26603", " C10047" })
public void testDoSomething() {
     Assert.assertTrue(false);
}
```

Similarly more cleaner case would be:

***CASE 2:***

```
@TestInfo(id={ "C26603", "C10047" })
```

*As you can see this case 2 is more clear than the case 1. This case 2 does not have white spaces in test ids.*

***How do I fetch these ids and make sure that they don't have that C character in beginning and just a pure number?*** For example, I just want `26603` for my first id and `10047` for 2nd one. There are some spaces in the id array (inside quotes). I want to trim everything of that (like white spaces) and just get the id. I am currently applying `for loop` to process each id and once I get the pure number, I want to make a 3rd party API call (API expects pure number as input and so removal of C as initial character and other white spaces is important).

Here is what I have tried:

```
TestInfo annotation = method.getAnnotation(TestInfo.class);
if(annotation!=null) {
        for(String test_id: annotation.id()) {
            //check if id is null or empty
            if (test_id !=null && !test_id.isEmpty()) {
         //remove white spaces and check if id = "C1234" or id = "1234"
                    if(Character.isLetter(test_id.trim().charAt(0))) {
                                test_id = test_id.substring(1);
                    }
                    System.out.println(test_id);
                    System.out.println(test_id.trim());
            }
      }
}
```

Above code gives me `C26603` and `not 26603` for the case 1. It works for the case 2.

***CASE 3:***

```
@TestInfo(id={ " 26603", " 10047" })
```

For this case, there is no C as beginning character of test id, so the function should be smart enough to just trim white spaces and go ahead.

Comment: I took a brief look through your profile, and since you're a fairly new user, could you have a look at [this](http://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)? You'll have a better experience on SO if you reward people for helping you out.

Comment: Got it, I will keep this in mind.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The simplest approach would be to just remove everything that is not a digit, using the regular expression non-digit character class (`\D`):

```
test_id = test_id.replaceAll("\\D", "");
```

Comment: Be aware that input `a3c5e` would result in `35`. If that's ok, then this is by far the easiest solution.

Comment: I was doing over engineering, perfect solution for me. Also, @Andreas I just want digit chars and this works.

Comment: @PratikJaiswal Good. Then you should accept this answer by clicking the checkmark. I was just clarifying the effect, so you could choose this option with your eyes wide open.

Answer (score 2):

I highly encourage you to debug your method. You will learn a lot.

If you take a look at your `if` statement here:

```
if(Character.isLetter(test_id.trim().charAt(0))) {
    test_id = test_id.substring(1);
}
```

When your `test_id` = " C1234", your condition is true. However, your problem becomes the `substring`.

ANSWER: `trim` it!

```
test_id = test_id.trim().substring(1);
```

Comment: This works for me too. Debugged a lot and of course, learnt a lot.